# BASH automating a process

Tags: bash

I managed to get Ubuntu running on a mobile device.  I need to automate some processes on it because user input is totally impossible without a convoluted setup and soldering wires.

I need to run "parted print" and then pipe "yes, fix, fix" to stdin   here is the desired output:

```
~ # parted /dev/block/mmcblk0 print
parted /dev/block/mmcblk0 print
Warning: /dev/block/mmcblk0 contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a
GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it
should.  Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't
understand GPT partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are
now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
Yes/No? yes
yes
yes
Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be.
This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller.
Fix, by moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)?
Fix/Ignore/Cancel? fix
fix
fix
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/block/mmcblk0 appears to be
used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 569312 blocks) or
continue with the current setting?
Fix/Ignore? fix
fix
fix
Model: MMC SEM16G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/block/mmcblk0: 15.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name        Flags
 1      131kB   262kB   131kB                xloader
 2      262kB   524kB   262kB                bootloader
 3      524kB   16.3MB  15.7MB               recovery
 4      16.8MB  33.6MB  16.8MB               boot
 5      33.6MB  83.9MB  50.3MB               rom
 6      83.9MB  134MB   50.3MB               bootdata
 7      134MB   522MB   388MB                factory
 8      522MB   1164MB  642MB                system
 9      1164MB  1611MB  447MB                cache
10      1611MB  2684MB  1074MB               media
11      2684MB  15.6GB  12.9GB               userdata
```

Here is what I've drafted..

```
#! /bin/bash
mkfifo Input
mkfifo Output
#Redirect commandline input from fifo to parted, Redirect output to fifo, background
cat Input &| - parted print >Output &
Line=""
while [ 1 ]
  do 
  while read Line
  do 
      if [ $Line == *Yes\/No\?* ]; then
        echo "yes">Input
      fi
      if [ $Line == *Fix\/Ignore/\Cancel\?* ]; then
        echo "fix">Input
      fi
      if [ $Line == *Fix\/Ignore\?* ]; then
        echo "fix">Input
      fi
      test $Line == *userdata* && break
  done<Output
  test $Line == *userdata* && break
done
```

But this does not work.  If someone could assist me in redirecting output from a program into a fifo, then analyzing that data and directing output into another fifo to be put back in the original program?   The desired results are in the first code block.

Comment: Any reason to not use [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always know what the needed inputs will be -- if they never change from run to run -- you can just redirect input from a file or from a HERE document and you don't need to do anything complicated.

If the needed inputs will change from run to run, you need to use something other than the shell because it will not make what you are trying to do possible. perl might be a good choice. (You don't need to use expect here because you're not trying to simulate a tty.)

Comment: Actually, i think I am emulating a TTY.  I need to be able to control the inputs to a program autonomously as though I were actually typing the commands out.

Comment: No, you are not. "Emulating a TTY" means running an interactive program under a pty because it will not function unless stdin and stdout are attached to /dev/tty -- examples are programs like telnet, slogin or emacs. By contrast, in this case, you were dealing with a normal program that is almost certainly happy if stdin and stdout are attached to pipes or what have you. popen(3) will work just fine.